# Mapbox gl integration with Next JS 13: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mark')

Tags: next.js, mapbox-gl-js

Attempting to integrate mapbox gl with Next JS 13 by following the [guide](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/guides/)

Very basic implementation:

```
"use client"

import React, {useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";

mapboxgl.accessToken = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN;

export const MapGL = ({}) => {

  // create the map and configure it
  // check out the API reference for more options
  // https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/
  const mapA = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: "mapA",
    style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v11",
    center: [74.854672, 34.061143],
    zoom: 14,
    pitch: 80,
  });


  return <div id="mapA" style={{width: "100%", height: "100vh"}} />;
};
```

Running this gives the following error:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mark')`

At the line:

`const mapA = new mapboxgl.Map({`

I've tried using `react-map-gl` already and was running into silent failures. Wondering if anyone has any experience integrating `Mapbox GL` generally with `Next JS 13`?